# Merge queue of std::maps into one std::map in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary

I have such a problem. I have a self-implemented thread-safe queue. I filled it with `std::map<std::string, int>`s, of the following structure: word - number of its occurrences. So I want to merge these maps to get the map, which will represent total number of occurrences of these words. I want to do it in parallel, so I implemented the following function(merge), but I think, that it can be the case, when mapping will finish, while there still will be maps to merge. How can I fix it? Here is my code of self-implemented queue, merge function and example of running.

```
template<class T>
class safeQueue {
    std::deque<T> que;
    mutable std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cvNotEmpty;
    std::condition_variable cvNotMax;
    size_t max_size = 10;

public:
    safeQueue(){}

    void setMaxSize(size_t newMax) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{m};
        max_size = newMax;
    }

    auto size() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{m};
        return que.size();
    }



    void pushFront(T item) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{m};
        cvNotMax.wait(lg, [this](){return max_size != que.size();});

        que.push_front(item);
        cvNotEmpty.notify_one();
    }

    void pushBack(T item) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{m};
        cvNotMax.wait(lg, [this](){return max_size != que.size();});

        que.push_back(item);
        cvNotEmpty.notify_one();
    }



    T popBack(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{m};
        cvNotEmpty.wait(lg, [this](){return que.size() != 0;});
        T result = que.back();
        que.pop_back();
        return result;
    }

    T popFront(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg{m};
        cvNotEmpty.wait(lg, [this](){return que.size() != 0;});
        T result = que.front();
        que.pop_front();
        return result;
    }
};
```

```
void merge(safeQueue<std::map<std::string, int>>& que) {

    while (que.size() >= 2) {

        std::map<std::string, int> map1 = que.popFront();
        std::map<std::string, int> map2 = que.popFront();
        for (const auto &element : map2) {
            map1[element.first] += element.second;
        }

        que.pushBack(map1);
    }

}
```

```
int main() {
    auto mergers = new std::vector<std::thread>;

    std::map<std::string, int> map1;
    std::map<std::string, int> map2;
    std::map<std::string, int> map3;
    std::map<std::string, int> map5;

    map1.insert(std::pair("a", 3));
    map1.insert(std::pair("b", 3));
    map1.insert(std::pair("c", 3));
    map1.insert(std::pair("d", 3));
    map1.insert(std::pair("e", 3));
    map1.insert(std::pair("f", 3));

    map2.insert(std::pair("a", 3));
    map2.insert(std::pair("b", 3));
    map2.insert(std::pair("c1", 3));
    map2.insert(std::pair("d", 3));
    map2.insert(std::pair("e1", 3));
    map2.insert(std::pair("f1", 3));

    map3.insert(std::pair("a", 3));
    map3.insert(std::pair("b", 3));
    map3.insert(std::pair("c2", 3));
    map3.insert(std::pair("d", 3));
    map3.insert(std::pair("e2", 3));
    map3.insert(std::pair("f2", 3));

    map5.insert(std::pair("a", 3));
    map5.insert(std::pair("b", 3));
    map5.insert(std::pair("c4", 3));
    map5.insert(std::pair("d", 3));
    map5.insert(std::pair("e4", 3));
    map5.insert(std::pair("f4", 3));


    safeQueue<std::map<std::string, int>> que;
    que.pushBack(map1);
    que.pushBack(map2);
    que.pushBack(map3);
    que.pushBack(map5);

    int num_mergers = 3;

    for (int i =0; i < num_mergers; i++) {
        mergers->emplace_back(std::thread(merge, std::ref(que)));
    }

    for (int k=0; k < num_mergers; k++) {
        mergers->at(k).join();
    }

    std::map<std::string, int> map_res = que.popBack();

    for (const auto& c : map_res) {
        std:: cout << c.first + " " << c.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i wouldnt do the merging in parallel, because it is inherently non-parallel. For any single merge two threads might want to access the same element in the map, hence I would not expect a speedup from doing the merge in parallel

Comment: Unrelated: `map1.insert(std::pair("a", 3));` is better written `map1.emplace("a", 3);`

Comment: @idclev463035818. You might not understood me correctly. In my code I can not access elements of the same maps in different threads, as I pop maps from the queue, which is thread-safe. The idea is my threads can not work on one map at simultaniously

Comment: i dont fully understand, if you want to merge the results into one map in the end in parallel, then many threads do have to access the same map

Comment: @idclev463035818 I want just merge maps in parallel - means multiple threads will take maps from the queue, the push the resulting map back in the queue, so internal merging will not be done in parallel.

Comment: `T result = que.front();`. This looks like a copy to me, and that's not going to be cheap. If you're optimizing, start with the lowhanging fruit. Move that element instead, you'll pop it afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `safeQueue::size` may return outdated result, as another thread may insert or remove an element as soon as `safeQueue::size` releases the internal lock. For your `merge` function, this means that by the time you check the `while (que.size() >= 2)` condition, the size of the queue might have already changed. In particular, `merge` may return when queue size is more than 1.

You need to lock the internal queue mutex and perform three actions without releasing it:

1. Test the queue size. Return if less than 2.
2. Dequeue the first element.
3. Dequeue the second element.

You may still end up with more than one element in the queue after `merge` if some other threads are adding new elements to the queue besides `merge`. If that is the case, you need to be prepared for that or block those other threads until `merge` completes and you process its result.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I still have a question. Will it help me to always merge these maps correctly?

Comment: I mean that I can imagine situation, when there still will be maps to merge in the queue, while all of the threads are done.

Comment: @ДанилоКлименко You mean if there are other threads adding maps while you're merging? No, the algorithm you presented does not guarantee you won't have more than one map in the queue after merge in this case. As I said in the answer, you have to anticipate that possibility or prohibit adding maps and merging at the same time.

Comment: If I do, what you specified in your answer will it guarantee to work correctly, having no other threads(not mergers) writing to these queue?

Comment: @ДанилоКлименко Yes, the fix in the answer should make `merge` work correctly, provided that there are no other threads.